# Can a Borel Measurable function be surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Lets suppose we have $\Omega = [0,1]$ and let us have $\sigma$-algebra $F=\{\emptyset, [0,\frac{1}{3}],(\frac{1}{3},1],[0,1]\}$ and the function X is defined as
$$
X(w)=
\begin{cases}
3, \text{if }w\in[0,\frac{1}{3}]\\
-5, \text{if }w\in(\frac{1}{3},1]
\end{cases}
$$

Now my question is if I add more values to the random variable will it still be measurable w.r.t. to $F$ above?

Comment: Surjective to which co-domain ? $\mathbb R$ ? Of course not... to $\{3,-5\}$, yes...

Comment: so lets say I do X(w)=
\begin{cases}
3, \text{if }w\in[0,\frac{1}{3}]\\
-5, \text{if }w\in(\frac{1}{3},1]\\
2, \text{if }w\in[0,\frac{1}{3}]
\end{cases}

then it is still measurable w.r.t to F above? I wasn't sure if the surjection would change anything

Comment: The above function isn't well-defined. You've defined $2=X(0)=3$.

Comment: I understand that it isn't well-defined, but that is how I understand the question. Mby I am understanding the question wrong.

Comment: I thought this was your question? Well, $X^{-1}(\{y\})\in F$ for every $y\in \mathbb{R}$ if $F$ is measurable. This implies that an $F$-measurable map can at most attain two different values.

Comment: It is not my question, this question was posed to me and I do not understand how to answer this. For me it feels like a question that would never actually happen since like you pointed out before the function is poorly defined.

Comment: Since the function $X$ in the question already has values at all points $w$ in the domain $\Omega$, the phrase "add more values" makes no sense.